# tpl can't see smarty variables

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I'm trying to made module for Prestashop. But my tpl file can't see variables.

**payicon.php:**

```
function hookFooter($params){
    $group_id="{$base_dir}modules/mymodule/payicon.php";

    $smarty = new Smarty;
    $smarty->assign('group_id', '$group_id');
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payicon.tpl');
    return false;
}
```

**payicon.tpl:**

```
<div id="payicon_block_footer" class="block">
    <h4>Welcome!</h4>
    <div class="block_content">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{$group_id}" title="Click this link">Click me!</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

This is install:

```
public function install() {
    if (!parent::install() OR !$this->registerHook('Footer'))
    return false;

    return Db::getInstance()->execute('
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'pay_icon` (
            `id_icon` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
            `icon_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `icon_img` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
            `icon_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id_icon`)
        )  ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;');
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try: `$smarty->assign('group_id', $group_id);`

Comment: The fact that you see the {$} means either php or smarty doesn't parse the `tpl`. Take a good look at your installation.

Comment: What doues: `$this->display(__FILE__, 'payicon.tpl');`? Does it run: `$smarty->display('payicon.tpl');`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php - see the documentation. `__FILE__` = The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

Comment: But it's open my tpl file. I need to write $smarty->display('payicon.tpl');?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about prestashop but I can tell you about smarty and PHP. I can see many obvious issues in the code

**1)**
`$base_dir` isn't available in the function. add

```
global $base_dir;
```

in start of the function to make it available in this function's scope.

**2)**

```
 $smarty = new Smarty;
```

This line shouldn't be there I think. This is initializing a new `Smarty` instance which has nothing to do with the code outside the function.
Replace this line with

```
global $smarty;
```

which will make global `$smarty` (instance of `Smarty` class) available in this function

**3)**

```
$smarty->assign('group_id', '$group_id');
```

is wrong. Replace it with

```
$smarty->assign('group_id', $group_id);
```

***POSSIBLE* Solution**
As your question isn't getting much attention, I'll try to come up with an answer to, at least, get you in the right direction (if not solve your issue)

try replacing this function with

```
public function hookFooter($params){
    global $base_dir;
    global $smarty;

    $group_id="{$base_dir}modules/mymodule/payicon.php";

    $smarty->assign('group_id', '$group_id');
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payicon.tpl');
}
```

**Update**

My bad :D. forgot to replace the `'$group_id'` in final code. Try this

```
public function hookFooter($params){
    global $base_dir;
    global $smarty;

    $group_id="{$base_dir}modules/mymodule/payicon.php";

    $smarty->assign('group_id', $group_id);
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payicon.tpl');
}
```

Comment: thanks but it still don't work right. it doesn't show $group_id value <a title="Click this link" href="$group_id">Click me!</a>

Comment: are you sure you made the edit I mentioned in point (3)? `$smarty->assign('group_id', $group_id);`?

Comment: Yes, I just trying to do this, but now I have even more questions)

Comment: this will help http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-WhatisaPrestaShopmodule I'm curious if the code solved your *that particular* problem

Comment: Thanks, that was first that I read. I just have another problems now

Comment: if you've other problems that are unrelated to the current question (and you want SO guys to help you out on that as well) then you should start a new question to keep this question relevant.

Comment: You cannot include a smarty variable {$base_dir} into a php file. It is not defined and it doesn't work! As for $smarty variable, `global $smarty` is correct